# AngularJS $http.post request is canceled by Chrome

Tags: angularjs, http

I've been googling this for hours...

here's my angularJS code:

```
var FrontControllers = angular.module('FrontControllers', [] );

FrontControllers.controller('LoginController', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http){

    $scope.user = {};

    $scope.login = function() {
        console.log($scope.user);
        $http({
            url: '/webapi/login',
            method: 'POST',
            data: $scope.user
        }).success(function (data) {
            alert("success!");
        }).error(function(data) {
            alert("failed =(");
        });

    };
}]);
```

here's the accompanying html

```
<div ng-controller="LoginController" id="login" class="box">

    <form novalidate role="form" action="/webapi/login" id="loginForm">                   
        <label for="signin" class="sr-only">Email or Username</label> 
        <input ng-model="user.username" type="text" autofocus class="form-control input-lg" id="username" name="username" size="20" placeholder="email or username">

        <label for="password" class="sr-only">Password</label> 
        <input ng-model="user.password" type="password" class="form-control input-lg" id="password" name="password" size="10" placeholder="password">

       <button ng-click="login()" type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-bright btn-block">Login</button>
    </form>

</div>
```

No matter what I do, I end up with a POST request that gets cancelled.  I've previously succeeded in logging in to /webapi/login with standard jQuery ajax code.  The server is configured for AJAX, so there's no need for a urlencode header.  The Payload looks correct, identical to the one that sent by jQuery ajax.

What might be the problem?

This is from Chrome developer/network:

```
Provisional headers are shown
Accept:application/json, text/plain, */*
Content-Type:application/json;charset=UTF-8
Origin:http://ec2-54-86-242-50.compute-1.amazonaws.com
Referer:http://ec2-54-86-242-50.compute-1.amazonaws.com/
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/38.0.2125.104 Safari/537.36
X-DevTools-Emulate-Network-Conditions-Client-Id:BB96CDC3-AD63-D024-E814-4726DF4843D8
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Angular will not `preventDefault()` if the `action` parameter is set. See [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/form)

> For this reason, Angular prevents the default action (form submission to the server) unless the  element has an action attribute specified.

You should probably also use `ng-submit="login()` on the `<form>` instead of `ng-click`, so that it will submit the form when the user presses Enter

Comment: thanks!  Removing the action parameter worked.  (and I could literally kiss you.  I spent 4 hours trying to get the stupid form to work.)

Comment: Thanks Austin!
I can't express the feelings, but it worked for me when i removed the action keyword from html page.
Thanks a ton! :)

Answer (score 0):

Try removing form's

```
action="/webapi/login"
```

and button's

```
type="submit"
```

Comment: This worked as well.  I gave the other response the checkmark because it came first.  Thanks so much!