# AngularJs $http get not working 1st time but does on subsequent invocations

Tags: angularjs, spring

All:
I have an Iframe tag on a simple HTML page and inside this Iframe tag is a HTML form - lets call it a widget.  Its a form where the user can enter search criteria and click on a button to obtain the search results. I have decided to use Angularjs to make the necessary DB calls to a REST service that returns the search results back to the widget for display.

In testing this I enter a value in a textbox on the widget, that value being a value that I know exists in a particular table I'm testing against.

Here is my $http get call:

```
            $http
        .get('http://localhost/XXXXService/folder/getfolders/' +
            $scope.formData.srchterm   **==>** mapped to search textbox

        ).then(function successCallback(response) {
            // this callback will be called asynchronously
            // when the response is available
            //$scope.formData = response;
            //$scope.nrdFolderDataArray = response;
            console.log('Success retrieving data.');
            console.log(response.length);
            console.log('response:');
            console.log(response);
        }, function errorCallback(response) {
            // called asynchronously if an error occurs
            // or server returns response with an error status.
            console.log('Error occurred retrieving data.');
            console.log(response.status);
            console.log('returned data count:');
            console.log(response.size);
            console.log('response:');
            console.log(response);
        });
```

This call is inside a function called "submitForm" that is mapped to the widget with a "ng-submit="submitForm()" attribute on the submit button.  And yes there are several log statements so I can try and figure out what is going on here.  And what is happening is this: after entering a value in the textbox, THE FIRST TIME the search button is clicked the .get command does not work.  I does not make the call to the REST service.  I know this because I wrote the REST service and made sure I put in plenty of log statements while doing so and there are no log statements in the log file from the REST service.  Instead the errorCallback block runs and I see all those log statements in the console.  The "response" (object?) after THE FIRST call looks like this:

```
Object {data: null, status: 0, config: Object, statusText: ""}  Method = GET Status = (canceled) type xhr
```

Further, in FF there is no response data to view in the Net tab of Firebug upon THE FIRST call, but there is response data to view in all subsequent calls.
So, interestingly enough each subsequent invocation of that $http.get call works!  I see log statements in the log file from the REST service method and the successCallback block runs and I can see my data via those console.log messages.

Also, if I were to change the search value in the text box, which would then be THE FIRST TIME we would be searching for data for that new key, once again, the call does not work, but does work on subsequent clicks on the "search" button for that new key value.

I really am not sure if I have a CORS issue here since, other than THE FIRST calls each subsequent $http.get call works like a champ.  Its just that very first call or first call after the search key has changed that the $http.get does not want to work.

I have tried setting headers in the .get call and I have tried using
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost/7001") as per 
https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service-cors/ but I continue to have this issue on the first time invoking this .get call.

I've been dealing with this issue for way too many hours now and would sure appreciate some input as to why this is happening.

I'm sorry for being verbose here.  I wanted to explain my issue thoroughly. 
Please help.
Thank you
-g

Comment: Oh.. I should have mentioned this.  Both the widget code and the REST service are on localhost...

Comment: Far too much to read

Comment: Yes I know.  It is a long posting.  I'm sorry about the length.  As stated I wanted to get as much information out there.  Anyway I found the solution in this SO post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26684991/angularjs-http-post-request-is-canceled-by-chrome