# Angularjs $http post method request getting cancel

Tags: angularjs

I'm doing call from angularjs app to Rest web service. Most of the times request getting cancel. Sometimes first call it's getting cancel or sometimes second call getting cancel. And sometimes it's work fine.

code is:

```
$http({
    method : 'POST',
    url : 'https://hostname:8080/myapp/api/j/save-file',
    data : {fileName: 'abc.txt'}
}).success(function (data) {
    alert("success");
}).error(function (data) {
    alert("failed: ", data);
});
```

[image]

Comment: Are you getting any error in developer console ?

Comment: @SudhirOjha, No. I'm not getting any error.

Comment: Similar question [AngularJS $http.post request is canceled by Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26684991/angularjs-http-post-request-is-canceled-by-chrome)

Comment: @SudhirOjha, thanks for your response. But i'm not using any forms. I'm just doing call on page loads

Answer (score 0):

```
$http({
    method : 'POST',
    url : 'http://localhost:8080/myapp/api/j/save-file',
    data : {fileName: 'abc.txt'}
}).success(function (data) {
    alert("success");
}).error(function (data) {
    alert("failed: ", data);
});
```

remove https and place HTTP will resolve your issue.

:-) make sure you have called perfect API with the perfect route.

:-) if you are calling internal API then you can `/myapp/api/j/save-file`.

Comment: Ravel, After I removed https then I'm getting status 301 code.

Comment: I'm not calling internal api. I'm calling anothe web app service

Comment: @AnilJagtap, Ok no problem, when you are calling `localhost` APIs then you need not add `https`.

Comment: I updated my question. Instead of localhost I gave host name of web application. Can you please check it once?

Comment: @AnilJagtap, As I said It will never work with `https` in my above comment and answer as well. if you deploy on the secure server then you can use `https`.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2746047/why-not-use-https-for-everything
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19254029/angularjs-http-post-does-not-send-data these will help you to understand the concepts if you want to understand. first, try to understand how it works then implement this functionality. you will surely do it. :-)

Comment: Switching from HTTPS to HTTP won't fix an AJAX request getting canceled. That just shows a complete lack of understanding of what the difference between HTTP and HTTPS is. Furthermore, if the web app service you're calling serves HTTP, it's not going to work at *all* if you do HTTPS.

Comment: And to clarify, the 301 HTTP status code makes sense; it's probably the API saying "Hey, you're trying to access this over HTTP; use HTTPS instead!".

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing more about what's sending the request, the webserver you're sending it to, etc., we really can't diagnose this too much. However, I can offer the following advice:

1. HTTP vs HTTPS won't make *any* difference here. If you're sending to a site that explicitly uses the protocol you're not using, you'll either get something like an HTTP 404 error, or a 301 (redirect) status.
2. "Perfect" route also doesn't make a lick of sense. Of course, if you are trying to access a route at the wrong address, it won't work, but you'd still get a 404 (or 500, or whatever).
3. Yes, you can use a relative URL for accessing stuff on the same server, but you can *also* use the full absolute URL. It makes *no* difference here, and does not explain at all why your request is getting cancelled.

Here's a test. What happens if you comment out *every* other 'thing' in your AngularJS app, leaving just the `app` definition itself, the `controller` definition, and try running it like that way? Does it still cancel? Try to find out at what point it's cancelling by breaking it down to the bare essentials.

If that still cancels, what about (as much as I hate using it) a jQuery `$.post()` request, to see if it's some issue specific with AngularJS and how you're using it?? Does the same error (with jQuery *or* AngularJS) happen in Firefox, Chrome, and any other browsers you have?

EDIT:

I've made a quick JS fiddle over at https://jsfiddle.net/cLu04r1t/1/ , using the same `$http` method you're using . Does your code throw the same error with this minimalist example (if you replace the URI I send it to with your example)?

Finally, take a look over at [What does status=canceled for a resource mean in Chrome Developer Tools?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12009423/what-does-status-canceled-for-a-resource-mean-in-chrome-developer-tools). Could any of *those* be culprits behind why your AJAX request is getting cancelled?

Comment: I'm not using JQuery. It's pre angular js app and I want to call third party web service url. Means my another web application web service url

Comment: Sorry, lemme clarify. I meant trying just a regular HTTP request with something simple like jQuery's `$.post()` to see if there's some more general issue with your browser/setup by basically eliminating any "complexity". Just stick it on your page via a script tag or something. If jQuery works, and AngularJS doesn't/isn't, then you know there's some configuration issue with AngularJS.